# Friendly URL for RazorPage with query string

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, razor-pages

I would like to create friendly routes that map to different query string values of a single Razor Page and it's base GET handler. I'd be fine with switching the query string to being a part of the route as well. The idea is we have a single page that loads a file list and can filter. I'd prefer it if the URL was more straight forward. If it's not possible I could just go with `/Files/In` or `/Files/Out`

**Example**

```
/Files?direction=In  -> /In
/Files?direction=Out -> /Out
```

Is there any way to do something like this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use route data parameters which  are defined in a Route Template as part of the @page directive in the .cshtml file :

```
@page "{direction?}"
```

Then you can access the route parameter value in OnGet method of your file page :

```
public void OnGet(string direction)
{
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(direction))
     {
           //filter files based on direction

     }
}
```

You can pass direction value as `/Files/In` or `/Files/Out` , without filter directly use `/Files` .